# Rules for playing a sorry card?

Tags: sorry

If you draw a sorry card but you do not have a man in start, are you able to take one of your live players and bump one of your live player opponents back to start?

The Sorry rules for a sorry card play are:

> Take one pawn from your “START” position and move it to any legal
>   space occupied by an opponent (no “HOME”, “START”, or “SAFETY ZONE”
>   spaces), and bump the opponent back to their “START” space. If you
>   have no pawns in the “START” space, or there are no legal pawns to
>   bump, end your turn.

Comment: It'sliterally written in the rules you quoted: "*If you have no pawns in the “START” space [...] end your turn.*"

Answer (score 5):

If the rules of a game say that you should use a man from position X to do Y, and you have no man in position X, you cannot do Y since you have no piece that qualifies to do Y. So if you have no man available in your "start" position, you do not have "what it takes" to "Sorry" someone.